# How can I make bash convert '~'?

Tags: bash, path

Some programs do not recognize tilde shortcut  in filenames and expect full canonical paths, e.g. `/home/dave/myfile.txt` instead of `~/myfile.txt`.

Is there a way to make bash replace `~` and `~user` by full canonical paths anytime a tilde is used?

Comment: Can you provide examples of commands where ~ isn't expanded by bash ? The shell should do it. Called programs do not need to interpret it.

Comment: Consider replacing ~ with $HOME as well.

Comment: For example, some Perl scripts won't recognize paths with `~`. So what I would like bash to do is explicitly expand the path, just like it auto completes when I hit the `tab key`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure about perl, but in bash script you can do that conversion with eval:

```
eval dir='~user/somedir'
```

$dir will contain full path, i.e. /home/user/somedir at this point.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a command in the Bash shell, like:

```
command ~/myfile.txt
```

the shell first makes the expansion of `~` (unless it's quoted) then it run the command with the result.

But it's true, some programs don't interpret the `~`, for example:

```
$ cat "~/myfile.txt"
~/myfile.txt: No such file or directory
```

but this works insted:

```
nano "~/myfile.txt"
```

But this behavior is masked by the Bash expansion, so **you don't need any further interpretation**.

Maybe it's obvious, but note that if a program uses a configuration files and expects some paths in it, it's not a Bash duty expand them.